# Recombinations between Distant coronaviruses

Tags: coronavirus, recombination

With recombination I mean long ones, say > 1000 nucleotides, so that the two parents must be coronaviruses and the two pieces of genomes must have compatible genomic coordinates for the recombinant to be viable.

Though co-infection by distant CoVs (for example SARS-related with HKU2-related) are often found in nature, most recombinations occur between closely related coronaviruses.
One thing preventing distant recombination is the TRS (a small motif causing most sub-genomic mRNA junctions) which must be compatible when the 5' part of an ORF is included in the *transferred* piece of genome. Another one is the complicated interactions between the host and viral proteins and RNA.

However, some rare distant recombinations might occur.

- An example is Deltacoronavirus which is a distant genus except in the spike where it falls into Alphacoronavirus (though a bit distant to others).
- There are also two Alphacoronaviruses: HKU2 (a normal one) and Wencheng shrew CoV (a distant one) that form a separate "genus" in the spike.
- Swine enteric coronavirus (SeCoV) is a near perfect recombinant between two distant alphacoronaviruses, PEDV and TGEV (both responsible of enteric swine diseases).[image]

**Are there other examples of recombination between distant Coronaviruses?** Note that I mentioned one proven and three *putatives* recombinations, ie. we often don't have the triplet [major parent, minor parent, recombinant] as it is the case with SeCoV.

Discussing related lab experiments might be interesting as well (of note replacing VSV's G protein by various attachment&fusion proteins often produce viable chimera).

Comment: In every case recombinations are *rare* as not many were found in the 2 million SARS-CoV-2 sequences, but they end being common when looking at the long-term evolutionary history of a given lineage.

Comment: Recombination between distant viruses is less likely to produce a viable virus, which is why is rarely observed (recombination rate in a cell may be nearly as high as for similar viruses).